# Text editor for maths unicode symbols on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, text-editor

I have an iPad Pro 2020.

I am looking for a text editor which allows me to easily type in some standard maths characters in Unicode: Greek letters, arrows, etc.

On a laptop, for example with Sublime Text, I can use the usual LaTeX commands (\alpha, \to, \subset, …) and the editor automatically converts to Unicode. (I think they call this Math Preview.)

Is there an iPad equivalent?

Comment: Apple Pages supports [MathML](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202501)